# Fade button image to another button image

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, fade

I have a website to which I would like to add a little CSS animation. At the moment I have simple rollover images as navigation bar buttons. I would like to add fading effect,as it is now, but prettier, you now what I mean,transitions.  is the website and the navigation bar, so I would like to have the same navigation bar but with a fading transition effect. I have tried a lot of stuff,but nothing worked for me, get the fade but it doesnt change to the other image. Thank you for the help!

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons"><a href="../index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"                  onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','../gallery/images/buttons2_01.png',1)"><img      src="../gallery/images/buttons_01.png" width="100" height="42" id="Home" /></a><a    href="../Resume.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"  onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Resume','','../gallery/images/buttons2_02.png',1)"><img src="../gallery/images/buttons_02.png" width="110" height="42" id="Resume" /></a><a href="../Portfolio.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Portfolio','','../gallery/images/buttons2_03.png',1)"><img src="../gallery/images/buttons_03.png" width="108" height="42" id="Portfolio" /></a><a href="../Contact.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Contact','','../gallery/images/buttons2_04.png',1)"><img src="../gallery/images/buttons_04.png" width="110" height="42" id="Contact" /></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons {
 width:428px;
 height:42px;
 margin-top:48px;
 float:right;
 margin-right:35px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance, try it with opacity!

```
#buttons {
 width:428px;
 height:42px;
 margin-top:48px;
 float:right;
 margin-right:35px;
 opacity:1;         /*Here the full opacity*/
 transition: opacity 1s;

#buttons:hover {     /*Hover means when you go over the element with the mouse*/
  opacity: 0.6;}
```

If you don't like this just tell me and I show you something else!
Best,

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That doesnt do anything to the effect,its still the same. What should the HTML look if I use your method?

Comment: check the answer now! I corrected a mistake that I made. Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks,that code did the trick. Not in that way,I added a class to every button image and then that code to the class. But works,thanks again ;)